# Determine iOS application platform

Tags: ios, multiplatform

I have an application I've been handed to test, and I'm — shall we say — less than impressed?

I believe the company that built the application for my client didn't build it as an iOS native application; my gut feel is they leveraged one of the multi-target platforms because that's what they're comfortable with. The application's usability is particularly poor, and it just doesn't behave the way an iOS application should.

How can I tell whether this application is native or built on some OS-agnostic platform? Any big give-aways that can tell me?

FWIW, the iPad is the only target platform for this device. It won't need to run anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that it doesn't have the look and feel of a regular iOS app? It's possible that it has been developed in AIR, HTML5, etc. I don't know if there is much way of doing this without jailbreaking the device.

You could, of course, ask around or post a screenshot and see what others think.

Answer (score 0):

Get the binary out of the device, using softs like DiskAid (free for that part - no jailbreak required), and study it. You may get important infos through a disassembler, such as Hopper, which has support for ARM.

If you can't read assembly, study the application's resources. It may also give you some hints. Again, a software like DiskAid will allow that.

Answer (score 0):

While "some OS-agnostic platform" is a bit broad, there is an easy way to tell if an app was made with PhoneGap, arguably one of the most popular OS-agnostic platforms.

1. Copy the `.ipa` file you've been sent (or find it on your filesystem
   and copy it).
2. Rename the copy `WhatEverTheAppNameIs.zip`.
3. Extract the zipped folder and open it.
4. Open the folder named "Payload" (If it isn't already).
5. Right-click on `BlahBlah.app` and select "Show Package Contents".
6. Inspect the bundle.

Check for the presence of a `www` folder. If it's contents are sizable (compared with the packages contents in general) there's a good chance the whole app was made with PhoneGap.

It's also illuminating to click on the `index.html` file in the `www` folder just to see how much of the app runs in desktop Safari.

You may also discover other evidence of OS-agnostic platforms by examining the bundle further.